# Why can't I get the current ID and place in another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to create a simple news and image system, I first need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() and execute scalar, but I'm not having much luck. I get a:

> The name 'newID' does not exist in the current context

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  

            //Save files to disk
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/admin/news/" +  FileName));

            //Add Entry to DataBase
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            int newID = 0;

            string strQuery = @"insert into tblFiles (FileName, FilePath) values(@FileName, @FilePath); select cast(scope_identity() As int);";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "/images/admin/news/" + FileName;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    newID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch 
                {
                }
            }
        }

        if (newID > 0)

        {
            string strAddNewsQuery = @"insert into tblNews (newsTitle, newsDate, newsSummary, newsContent, newsPicID) 
                    values(@newsTitle, @newsDate, @newsSummary, @newsContent, @newsPicID)"; 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strAddNewsQuery, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@newsTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsDate", txtnewsdate.Text);            
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsSummary", txtnewssummary.Text);            
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsContent", txtnewsmaincontent.Text);  
                command.Parameters.Add("@newsPicID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newID;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally {
                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SQL is invalid: `select cast(scope_identity() As int;` is missing the closing parenthesis, but `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is already an integer value so the `CAST` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Also, you're storing duplicate data in your database, there is no meaningful difference between your `FileName` and `FilePath` column values.

Comment: @Dai thank you. Good spot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An int does not have properties you can access. Change

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsPicID", newID.Value);
```

into

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsPicID", newID);
```

Even better is to use parameters with the database value type specified.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@newsPicID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newID;
```

But you are trying to get the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` of table `tblNews`, not from `tblFiles` to be used in `tblNews` as `newsPicID`. You need to get `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from the first database command.

**UPDATE**

And you need to assign the connection to the command.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a complete snippet to get you started. Notice the wrapping with `using`. This ensures proper disposal of connections.

```
int newID = 0;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
    command.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "/images/admin/news/" + FileName;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        newID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}

if (newID > 0)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strAddNewsQuery, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@newsTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
        //etc
        command.Parameters.Add("@newsPicID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newID;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I now get a: `System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized` - any idea what I can do to get round this?

Comment: Do I not need to insert the picture into the picture table, and retrieve the ID of the row inserted and then after that is successful insert the news item with the correct pic ID?

Comment: Yes, but you execute the scalar on `command`, not `cmd`. And even if you were, you are assining `newID` to the second query before you have the chance to get the proper scalar. `newID` will always be 0 in table `tblNews`

Comment: can I use `try Execute.Scalar` and then `finally command.ExecuteNonQuery`? Would that work for it? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thanks so much @VDWWD - however now I have a: `The name 'newID' does not exist in the current context` on `if (newID > 0)`. Really can't thank you enough :-)

Comment: Did you split it in 2 separate methods?, because `int newID = 0;` is right on top of my snippet in the same scope.